# Tree structure in angular 4

Tags: angular, treeview

I want to implement a hierarchy structure dynamically in my angular 4  application. The example image given below.

[image]

Is there any libraries to do this in angular. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using the PrimeNG library. They have an org chart component. See here: https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/organizationchart

Comment: I tried it, but doesn't work I think they have syntax problem on there code